# Setting dpms in Awesome WM

Tags: x11, power-management, awesome-wm

If I do the following from terminal, then the screen turns off after 10 seconds of inactivity, as I expect.

```
xset +dpms dpms 0 0 10
```

However, if I try to do the same from `init.lua`, then it does not work.

```
awful.spawn("xset +dpms dpms 0 0 10")
```

I even tried `awful.spawn.with_shell()`, but it still doesn't work.

Of course, I plan to use a higher timeout, but first I just want it to work.

Comment: Well, any error output from awesome when you run that? I don't know where your awesome's stderr goes to, but it might make sense to check there. Also, are you starting other programs together with awesome? Could one of those influence the DPMS settings (e.g. gnome-settings-daemon)?

Answer (score -1):

Replace the awful.spawn() command with the lua command os.execute().

Comment: Why would that change anything?